# exponential arrival and service rates

Tags: des, exponential

I have 2 agent types (say patients). each patient type will need a service after an exponential amount of time. 
We also have 2 different services A and B which have different service rates (exponential) for different patient types. 
So in total we have 4 different arrival rates and 4 different service rates.
How can I model this? How can I say that these 2 patient types are going to use those 2 servers since arrival and service rates are exponential? right now I am using probability in selectoutput but the results I get are not exact. When we have exponential arrival and service rates,
how can we say that the agents are going to use the s[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnFqm.png)ervers? Is there a better way to model this? any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What I could make up from the text and the model you showed is that you have 2 different patients which are also split in 2 different services which they need and that causes the 4 different delays. So patient 1 and 2 and service A or B cause 4 delays? If this is the case than I would make a parameter in the agent called serviceType which Amy Greer first stated and define this parameter at the exit of the first selectOutputs (or exit of delays is also possible). With the select output you can assign the patients to the right service which Amy already stated by using a condition statement.

Now if you want to use different processtimes in your services for the different patients, which consist of 2 different processtimes for service A and B (1&2 for A and 1&2 for B) there are multiple way to do this. Personally I would make a database in my model in which I specify the process times (exponential distributions in this case) and do the delay time in service A and B through a database reference. If you are not familiar with how to do this, I uploaded a screenshot to this link [http://imgur.com/7x0xCUZ](https://imgur.com/7x0xCUZ). I'm not sure if I know exactly what you are trying to do but I think that this should resolve the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for your complete response. I really appreciate it, Actually, right now I have this Service-type parameter in my model, my problem is that what is the condition that splits patients of type 1 to 2 different services A and B and so do patient kind 2? I do not know what condition to use in order to send patients of type 1 and 2 to either of the services A or B? Do you have any idea of that?

Comment: usually we should specify the service rate (amount of time that each agent is going to receive the service) in the source block when the agents are being generated and we specify the arrival rates (the amount of time that should pass so that they become needy) in the delay block. the problem with my question is that how can I specify 2 different service rates in the source block? I know I can define parameter like service-type but how can I specify different service types for 1 agent type?